# Isomorphism of poset from covering relations

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

Let $(P,\preccurlyeq_P)$ and $(Q,\preccurlyeq_Q)$ be two posets. They are isomorphic if there exists a bijective map $f:P\to Q$ such that for all $a,b\in P$, $a\preccurlyeq_P b\Leftrightarrow f(a)\preccurlyeq_Q f(b)$.

If the poset $P$ is generated by the covering relation $\lessdot_P$ and $Q$ is generated by the covering relation $\lessdot_Q$,  is it true that  $P$ and $Q$ are isomorphic if there exists a bijective map $f:P\to Q$ such that for all $a,b\in P$, $a\lessdot_P b\Leftrightarrow f(a)\lessdot_Q f(b)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean with $P$ being generated by the covering relation $\lessdot$.
To me, it makes sense if it means that
$$a\leq b \Longleftrightarrow \exists c_1,\ldots,c_n \bigl( a=c_1\lessdot c_2 \lessdot \cdots \lessdot c_n = b \bigr).$$
In that case, in answer is yes.

Suppose that $f:P\to Q$ is a bijection satisfying $a\leq b$ iff $f(a)\leq f(b)$.
Now, if $a\lessdot b$, then $a\leq b$, whence
\begin{align}
a\lessdot b
&\Longrightarrow f(a)\leq f(b)\\
&\Longrightarrow \exists d_1,\ldots,d_n \bigl( f(a)=d_1\lessdot\cdots\lessdot d_n=b \bigr)\\
&\Longrightarrow a=c_1\lessdot\cdots\lessdot c_n=b,
\end{align}
where $c_i=f^{-1}(d_i)$.
As $a\lessdot b$, it follows that $n=2$ and $b=c_2$, and therefore, $f(b)=d_2$, whence $f(a)\lessdot f(b)$.
For the converse implication use $f^{-1}$ (which satisfies $c\leq d$ iff $f^{-1}(c)\leq f^{-1}(d)$).

Suppose now that $f:P\to Q$ is a bijection satisfying $a\lessdot b$ iff $f(a)\lessdot f(b)$.
If $a\leq b$, then there exist $c_1,\ldots,c_n$ such that 
$$a=c_1\lessdot\cdots\lessdot c_n=b,$$
and so
$$f(a)=f(c_1)\lessdot\cdots\lessdot f(c_n)=f(b),$$
yielding $f(a)\leq f(b)$.
Again, for the converse, use $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. What I meant is that, instead of proving the existence of the bijection $f$ satisfying $a\leq b$ in $P$ if and only if $f(a)\leq f(b)$ in $Q$, is it enough to show the existence of  such bijection $f$ satisfying: $a$ covers $b$ in $P$ if and only if $f(a)$ covers $f(b)$ in $Q$?

Comment: @Minah Well, it seems like that's precisely what I proved, isn't it? I mean, provided that the definition I assumed of a poset being generated by its covering relations is what you mean. Of course there are such posets (necessarily infinite) in which this doesn't happen.

Comment: That's right. Thank you so much.